# Isn’t the icon for [google-play] wrong?

Tags: bug, tags, sponsored-tags

The current icon for [google-play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play) (which is Google’s app store) is a gaming controller. I guess someone was confused by the “Play” part. That icon would be for Google Play Games, which is a different thing.

Comment: That tag is sponsored, someone is paying to get that "icon" there. You don't trust the competency of a marketing department?

Comment: I'm upvoting you for making the effort to come to meta and report something sensible you thought was a problem on the site. If more people did this and less people donvoted when they do, maybe more would be fixed on the site? (I know how meta votes work, but downvoting to say you disagree is pointless, an official answer will determine if this is something needing changing or not)_

Comment: @rene Regardless of if the OP does or does not, people do commit mistakes. This sounds like one

Comment: @rene I didn't know that! Then I guess is outside of we common people can do. It's ok, it's just a misplaced icon. =)

Comment: @James Thanks. I don't know a lot about how meta works, I just wanted to point out some very minor "issue". So minor it's a shame we are here wasting time. =)

Comment: Upvoted when I saw _"I guess someone was confused by the “Play” part."_ in your question :D

Comment: @rene was that sarcasm or serious?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it is what you want it to be ...

Comment: Might be a silly question: but do we distinguish sponsored tags just by their icon, or have I missed something that actually states it's sponsored? I suppose sponsored tags might not actually have an image if sponsor decided not to?

Comment: It's have a sponsored link (which is what the image seems attached to) that links to https://developers.google.com/games/services/ which is Google Play Games.

Comment: FWIW, The Icon is outdated nevertheless, it should rather look like [this](https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/product/1x/play_games_64dp.png)

Comment: @rene [As long as they used blockchain to implement the image then I think we can safely trust them...](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/voting_software.png)

Answer (score 7):

Half fixed, the [google-play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play) icon is now the one for **Google Play Services** instead of **Google Play Games**.

Sadly, still not exactly the **Google Play** icon.

Comment: I can imagine that exchange over in their marketing department: "Hey, some people on Stack Overflow noticed that you put in the wrong icon." "Oh, fill out a bug report, I'll get to it in a week." \*One week later\* "Wait what icon is it supposed to be? Darn, I should have asked originally, now I'll just look dumb if I ask now. Let's see, Google Play... Hey, one of our developers showed me a [chart](https://developers.google.com/android/images/play-services-diagram.png) to explain to me what Google Play was when I got the job, maybe this one is it."