# Does DigitalOcean own The Cloud? And all Web-Applications?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, sponsored-tags

I and other regulars in [the SOCVR chat-room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54871592#54871592) have today noticed that [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) now have their icon on the [cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud) and [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) tags (and possibly others<sup>1</sup>). Presumably, this is because the company has 'sponsored' those tags (i.e. paid money to Stack Overflow to get their icon displayed).

However, as far as I am aware, they do *not* have (sole) ownership of either The Cloud or (all) Web Applications.

So, is this a case of inappropriate advertising?

A similar case arose a [couple of years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393124/10871073), when a company sponsored the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag (and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)?). That case caused a significant outcry here on Meta.SO, and the icon was removed. Should the same be done in this case?

---

<sup>1</sup> Other tags that have been sponsored by DigitalOcean (thanks to the commentators for finding them); feel free to edit others in here:

[deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deployment) [continuous-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) …

---

Comment: I'm not sure it's working for them. I've purchased service from them in the past, and I didn't even recognize that mess of an icon as them.

Comment: @IanCampbell Same here. It was the keen eye of Jeanne Dark who pointed me to the company, and the ever-watchful Dharman also found it a bit later on.

Comment: Also relevant: a (former) staff member mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387263/13095326) that "The reason that you are not seeing the 18x16 logo on the actual tag, is that we only allow that for advertisers that own a copyright on the name of the tag." Did DigitalOcean snag a trademark on cloud when we weren't looking?

Comment: It is also on [tag:deployment]

Comment: @TylerH But not (yet) on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow). xD

Comment: How many tags are they on?! I spotted [tag:continuous-integration]

Comment: But not on [tag:digital-ocean-spaces] or [tag:digital-ocean-apps]

Comment: @dbc Well, that, in itself, makes the whole campaign look rather more sinister, IMHO.

Comment: Ugh, this ___again___ someone on SE's side messed up the sponsored tag association, ___again___.

Comment: @Cerbrus You have links to Meta posts for other cases?

Comment: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389531) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389531) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377170) [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376143) [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373510) [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373240) [7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363174)

Comment: The tag you've used, [[tag:sponsored-tags]], gives a few examples, @AdrianMole: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400338/2029983) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401454/2029983) (Cerbrus expresses the same distress in that one), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394830/2029983), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393818/2029983), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376143/2029983)... I could keep going ;)

Comment: That's just a few of them. This happens way too often. I'm also not particularly pleased that anyone can just "buy" generic tags.

Comment: @Larnu OK - Enough said. But please don't close this as a duplicate ... it's an issue that **must** be voiced and dealt with.

Comment: Yup Yup Yup, this shouldn't be the case. Not good, we'll fix it. We improved some messaging in our internal system to avoid these cases, this (I think) made us have this issue less frequent... But it slipped through. Apologies, and we'll fix it. I'll update this post when that's done.

Comment: I didn't say I was going to vote this closed as duplicate; it's *not* a duplicate. It's the same issue, yes, but with a different set of tags and a new instance of of the problem.

Comment: @JD-Stack Please feel free to post that comment as an answer ... I might even upvote and/or accept it. :-)

Comment: I promise to do so when we fix it (forces me to actually do it :P)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's fixed. Short story, even shorter: human mistake. We've actually built in some protections that should prevent us from making this mistake. These protections aren't 100%, because having that is practically impossible (or very very difficult) and because of that not really worth it.

Digging into older meta posts with the same issue I think we've had the same (similar) issue [around October 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401454/blazor-tag-has-incorrect-icon#comment799704_401617) and we've built some protections after that. I guess having this issue once every 2 years... is ok-ish.

It leaves me with one last thing: Thanks a lot for notifying us friendly on this. We really appreciate it.

Comment: I see it's removed from the other tags, but it is still there on the [tag:web-applications] tag. Is that caching?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - I re-checked all the toggles, and they are set correctly. So probably caching, I'll check again tomorrow. If it's not fixed by then we'll dig deeper

Comment: All cleared now - thanks very much for your swift attention to this issue.